# Everything is so slow after update Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates

I recently ran the following command in my terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

However, since then, I've been experiencing significant slowdowns. The boot time has increased by 200%, and every task takes much longer to complete. Simple actions like left-clicking, right-clicking, and moving the mouse around have become sluggish. Even launching an application now requires waiting for 20-30 seconds. Overall, it feels like the system's performance has decreased by around 2000%(not exagerating here). I didn't run any benchmarks before the update, but prior to it, a game I played was running smoothly at 60 FPS with plenty of mods and no stuttering. Now, it struggles to launch and runs at a maximum of 5 FPS.

This is the recent logs of apt

```
Start-Date: 2023-07-08  16:21:18
Commandline: apt install build-essential cmake curl libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev libgmp-dev e2fsprogs ninja-build qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils ccache rsync unzip texinfo libssl-dev
Requested-By: oscar (1000)
Install: libtext-unidecode-perl:amd64 (1.30-1, automatic), libxml-namespacesupport-perl:amd64 (1.12-1.1, automatic), tex-common:amd64 (6.17, automatic), libhiredis0.14:amd64 (0.14.1-2, automatic), texinfo:amd64 (6.8-4build1), libgmpxx4ldbl:amd64 (2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1, automatic), libmpc-dev:amd64 (1.2.1-2build1), libmpfr-dev:amd64 (4.1.0-3build3), libxml-sax-base-perl:amd64 (1.09-1.1, automatic), libxml-sax-perl:amd64 (1.02+dfsg-3, automatic), ccache:amd64 (4.5.1-1), libgmp-dev:amd64 (2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1), libxml-libxml-perl:amd64 (2.0207+dfsg+really+2.0134-1, automatic), libxml-sax-expat-perl:amd64 (0.51-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2023-07-08  16:21:21

Start-Date: 2023-07-08  16:21:46
Commandline: apt install libgtk-3-dev libpixman-1-dev libsdl2-dev libslirp-dev libspice-server-dev
Requested-By: oscar (1000)
Install: libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 (2.38.0-3, automatic), libspice-protocol-dev:amd64 (0.14.3-1, automatic), libjpeg-dev:amd64 (8c-2ubuntu10, automatic), libfribidi-dev:amd64 (1.0.8-2ubuntu3.1, automatic), libtiffxx5:amd64 (4.3.0-6ubuntu0.4, automatic), libatspi2.0-dev:amd64 (2.44.0-3, automatic), libepoxy-dev:amd64 (1.5.10-1, automatic), libjbig-dev:amd64 (2.1-3.1ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), libslirp-dev:amd64 (4.6.1-1build1), liblzma-dev:amd64 (5.2.5-2ubuntu1, automatic), libdatrie-dev:amd64 (0.2.13-2, automatic), libatk1.0-dev:amd64 (2.36.0-3build1, automatic), wayland-protocols:amd64 (1.25-1, automatic), libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:amd64 (2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2, automatic), libdeflate-dev:amd64 (1.10-2, automatic), libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64 (2.1.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), pango1.0-tools:amd64 (1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1, automatic), libgraphite2-dev:amd64 (1.3.14-1build2, automatic), libspice-server-dev:amd64 (0.15.0-2ubuntu4), libharfbuzz-gobject0:amd64 (2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1, automatic), libgtk-3-dev:amd64 (3.24.33-1ubuntu2), libtiff-dev:amd64 (4.3.0-6ubuntu0.4, automatic), libjpeg8-dev:amd64 (8c-2ubuntu10, automatic), libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 (2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1, automatic), libpango1.0-dev:amd64 (1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1, automatic), libthai-dev:amd64 (0.1.29-1build1, automatic)
End-Date: 2023-07-08  16:21:48

Start-Date: 2023-07-08  17:51:59
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: oscar (1000)
Install: linux-modules-5.17.0-1034-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1034.35, automatic), linux-oem-5.17-headers-5.17.0-1034:amd64 (5.17.0-1034.35, automatic), linux-headers-5.17.0-1034-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1034.35, automatic), linux-image-5.17.0-1034-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1034.35, automatic)
Upgrade: dpkg:amd64 (1.21.1ubuntu2.1, 1.21.1ubuntu2.2), libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, 0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1), linux-headers-oem-22.04:amd64 (5.17.0.1033.31, 5.17.0.1034.32), containerd.io:amd64 (1.6.20-1, 1.6.21-1), libxtables12:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1), docker-compose-plugin:amd64 (2.17.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal, 2.19.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal), mokutil:amd64 (0.4.0-1ubuntu2, 0.6.0-2~22.04.1), udev:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.9), krb5-locales:amd64 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1, 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2), python3-tz:amd64 (2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.0, 2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:23.0.3-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal, 5:24.0.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal), iptables:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libglx-mesa0:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libidn12:amd64 (1.38-4build1, 1.38-4ubuntu1), apt:amd64 (2.4.8, 2.4.9), mesa-common-dev:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), modemmanager:amd64 (1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1, 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2), gjs:amd64 (1.72.2-0ubuntu1, 1.72.2-0ubuntu2), libgjs0g:amd64 (1.72.2-0ubuntu1, 1.72.2-0ubuntu2), libcanberra-gtk3-module:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, 0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1), tzdata:amd64 (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0, 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2), brave-keyring:amd64 (1.13, 1.16), libldap-common:amd64 (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.9, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1), osinfo-db:amd64 (0.20220214-1ubuntu2.1, 0.20230518-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libgbm1:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libgbm1:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libgdm1:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.1, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu7.1, 2.06-2ubuntu7.2), libgbm-dev:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libfwupd2:amd64 (1.7.9-1~22.04.1, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.4.8, 2.4.9), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.9.6.1, 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.4), swtpm-tools:amd64 (0.6.3-0ubuntu3, 0.6.3-0ubuntu3.2), alsa-ucm-conf:amd64 (1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.5, 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.6), libinput10:amd64 (1.20.0-1ubuntu0.2, 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.3), libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.99.22.6, 0.99.22.7), libllvm15:amd64 (1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2, 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libllvm15:i386 (1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2, 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libudev-dev:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.9), libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), libkrb5support0:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.99.22.6, 0.99.22.7), swtpm:amd64 (0.6.3-0ubuntu3, 0.6.3-0ubuntu3.2), libxatracker2:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libudev1:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.9), libudev1:i386 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.9), apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4, 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), mesa-va-drivers:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), docker-buildx-plugin:amd64 (0.10.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal, 0.11.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), im-config:amd64 (0.50-2, 0.50-2ubuntu22.04.1), libosmesa6:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libosmesa6:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), docker-ce:amd64 (5:23.0.3-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal, 5:24.0.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal), libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.9, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1), apache2-bin:amd64 (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4, 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5), gdm3:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.1, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3), libappstream-glib8:amd64 (0.7.18-2, 0.7.18-2ubuntu1), dpkg-dev:amd64 (1.21.1ubuntu2.1, 1.21.1ubuntu2.2), libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:42.2-0ubuntu2.1, 1:42.6-0ubuntu1), libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), libkrb5-3:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), fwupd-signed:amd64 (1.51~22.04.1+1.2-3ubuntu0.2, 1.51.1~22.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1), xserver-common:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.9, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1), linux-oem-22.04:amd64 (5.17.0.1033.31, 5.17.0.1034.32), xserver-xorg-dev:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.9, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1), docker-ce-rootless-extras:amd64 (5:23.0.3-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal, 5:24.0.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), libk5crypto3:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1, 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2), grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 (1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14, 1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1), gns3-server:amd64 (2.2.38~jammy1, 2.2.40.1~jammy1), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.99.22.6, 0.99.22.7), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.52ubuntu0.3, 0.52ubuntu0.4), linux-firmware:amd64 (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.12, 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14), libip6tc2:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.1, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3), apache2-utils:amd64 (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4, 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5), xvfb:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.9, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1), grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu14, 2.06-2ubuntu14.1), grub2-common:amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu7.1, 2.06-2ubuntu7.2), libdpkg-perl:amd64 (1.21.1ubuntu2.1, 1.21.1ubuntu2.2), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libglapi-mesa:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), apt-transport-https:amd64 (2.4.8, 2.4.9), gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 (72~ubuntu5.22.04.1, 72~ubuntu5.22.04.2.1), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.9, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1), grub-common:amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu7.1, 2.06-2ubuntu7.2), brave-browser:amd64 (1.50.114, 1.52.130), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.481, 1.481.1), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.4, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5), apache2:amd64 (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4, 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5), gnome-session-canberra:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, 0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1), nautilus:amd64 (1:42.2-0ubuntu2.1, 1:42.6-0ubuntu1), libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, 0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1), nautilus-data:amd64 (1:42.2-0ubuntu2.1, 1:42.6-0ubuntu1), apt-utils:amd64 (2.4.8, 2.4.9), gns3-gui:amd64 (2.2.38~jammy1, 2.2.40.1~jammy1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libegl-mesa0:i386 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (1.7.9-1~22.04.1, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.13.6~22.04.1, 27.14.4~22.04), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3), linux-image-oem-22.04:amd64 (5.17.0.1033.31, 5.17.0.1034.32), grub-pc:amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu7.1, 2.06-2ubuntu7.2), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.4, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5), libcanberra0:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, 0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1), fwupd:amd64 (1.7.9-1~22.04.1, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), intel-media-va-driver:amd64 (22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1, 22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2), intel-media-va-driver:i386 (22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1, 22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.481, 1.481.1), libinput-bin:amd64 (1.20.0-1ubuntu0.2, 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.3)
End-Date: 2023-07-08  18:07:08
```

**inxi -Fxxxmprz**

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Framework product: Laptop (12th Gen Intel Core) v: A4
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Framework model: FRANMACP04 v: A4 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: INSYDE v: 03.04 date: 07/15/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 34.8 Wh (85.7%) condition: 40.6/55.0 Wh (73.9%)
    volts: 16.3 min: 15.4 model: NVT Framewo type: Li-ion serial: <filter>
    status: Charging cycles: 210
Memory:
  RAM: total: 31.06 GiB used: 4.43 GiB (14.3%)
  RAM Report:
    permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU:
  Info: 12-core (4-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1240P bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP smt: enabled arch: Alder Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 1.1 MiB
    L2: 9 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1887 high: 2100 min/max: 400/4400:3300 cores: 1: 400
    2: 2100 3: 2100 4: 2100 5: 2100 6: 2100 7: 400 8: 2100 9: 2100 10: 2100
    11: 2100 12: 2100 13: 2100 14: 2100 15: 2100 16: 2100 bogomips: 67584
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
    ports: active: DP-1 off: eDP-1 empty: DP-2,DP-3,DP-4 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:46a6 class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 508x286mm (20.0x11.3")
    s-diag: 583mm (23")
  Monitor-1: DP-1 model: Samsung SA300/350/360 serial: <filter>
    res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 92 size: 531x299mm (20.9x11.8")
    diag: 609mm (24") modes: max: 1920x1080 min: 720x400
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:51c8
    class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: a6:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:2725
    class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp166s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-158be9d6f392 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: br-284257aaa795 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: br-4f4034142147 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-4: br-50c1a94f7866 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-5: br-83bcc592b220 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-6: br-d31fb8f9c519 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-7: br-d673e36f520a state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-8: br-df578ec4c03a state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-9: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-10: veth5558887 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-11: vethacfdd2f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-12: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX210 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-10:6 chip-ID: 8087:0032 class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 1 state: up address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 725.11 GiB (77.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WDS100T1X0E-00AFY0
    size: 931.51 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 614900WD temp: 41.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 911.78 GiB used: 724.57 GiB (79.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
    mapped: vgubuntu-root
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.61 GiB used: 540.3 MiB (32.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 1.91 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/dm-2 mapped: vgubuntu-swap_1
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.8 C mobo: 46.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 3350 apt: 3317 flatpak: 14 snap: 19
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
    2: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
    4: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
    5: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
    6: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
    9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
    10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appimagelauncher-team-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-jammy.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gns3-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/security:zeek.list
    1: deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/zeek/xUbuntu_22.04/ /
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
    1: deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources
    1: deb [arch=amd64 i386] https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy main
Info:
  Processes: 414 Uptime: 21m wakeups: 1 Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5
  Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11/12 clang: 14.0.0-1ubuntu1 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

**sudo smartctl -t long -a /dev/nvme0n1**
Nothing alarming

I also switched to 2 different kernel version, nothing changed, system is still really slow.

**ps -eo comm,pcpu,pmem --sort -pcpu | head -10**

```
COMMAND         %CPU %MEM
gnome-shell     15.0  0.8
Xorg            12.6  0.3
gnome-terminal-  4.0  0.1
pulseaudio       2.1  0.0
moolticute       1.9  0.2
packagekitd      1.7  0.1
snapd            1.6  0.1
snap-store       0.9  0.3
systemd          0.8  0.0
```

**systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20**

```
51.807s vboxdrv.service
48.782s snapd.service
30.038s apparmor.service
13.539s snapd.apparmor.service
12.505s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 8.707s docker.service
 6.032s fwupd.service
 4.954s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 2.993s dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
 2.054s postfix@-.service
 1.041s ufw.service
 1.021s mullvad-early-boot-blocking.service
 1.007s systemd-resolved.service
  880ms snapd.seeded.service
  802ms systemd-oomd.service
  776ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  761ms networkd-dispatcher.service
  738ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  737ms ua-timer.service
  734ms user@1000.service
```

I hope the information provided is enough. This system has become unbearably slow (even after multiple reboots) to the point where it is simply unusable. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` please ?

Comment: @Zatigem 
```
51.807s vboxdrv.service
48.782s snapd.service
30.038s apparmor.service
13.539s snapd.apparmor.service
12.505s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 8.707s docker.service
 6.032s fwupd.service
 4.954s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 2.993s dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
 2.054s postfix@-.service
 1.041s ufw.service
 1.021s mullvad-early-boot-blocking.service
 1.007s systemd-resolved.service
  880ms snapd.seeded.service
  802ms systemd-oomd.service
  776ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  761ms networkd-dispatcher.service
  738ms systemd-timesyncd.service
```